# Probability and series. (I just need help with the arguments provided )

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this problem: Suppose that random variable X have possible values $1,2,\ldots,$ and $P(X=j)=\dfrac{1}{2^j}$.

Calculate P(X is even).

I did the following;
I noted that $P(X=2k)=\dfrac{1}{4^k}$ for all k positive integer.

Then I reasoned that if I have to calculate the probability that X is even, I should add all the probabilities for all k.

So
$$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{4^k}=\dfrac{4}{3}$$
then $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{4^k}=\dfrac{4}{3}-1=\dfrac{1}{3}.$$

Then I concluded that the probability P(X is even)=$\dfrac{1}{3}$.

BUT my problem is that I can't formally justify the steps that I did. For example, how can I garantee formally that the series index starts on 1? (I know that probability $\leq$ 1 but ... )

Also, how can I garantee that the probability is equal to the value of the given serie? Is my reasoning enough? I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct.  The justification comes from the fact that the support of $X$ is the **positive** integers; i.e., $$X \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}.$$  Therefore, the smallest *even-valued* outcome of $X$ is $X = 2$, and this occurs with probability $\Pr[X = 2] = 1/4$.  This is why your summation starts at $k = 1$ according to your notation:  $$\Pr[X = 2k] = \frac{1}{4^k},$$ hence $$\Pr[X \;\text{is even}] = \Pr[X = 2] + \Pr[X = 4] + \cdots + = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Pr[X = 2k].$$

Answer (score 2):

All the events $[X=2k]$ are **pairwise disjoint**, hence
$$
P(X \text{ is even})=P\left(\bigcup_{k\geq1} [X=2k]\right)=\sum_{k\geq1}P([X=2k]).
$$